# What kind of phrase is Acc-ing gerund?

Tags: gerund

Here's a sentence I'm working on now.

> - Tom saw [Jane reading the book].

I think 'saw' takes two arguments, "Tom" and "Jane reading the book". But I'm not sure what phrase that is, and what the head is in the phrase. And is it okay to consider that 'see' theta-marks Tom and the phrase? I cannot think of any appropriate theta role to assign to the phrase.. I've just started learning linguistics by my own so please help me out. Thank you in advance!

Comment: _Jane reading the book_ is what Tom saw; so is _the book_ in _Tom saw the book_. They should have the same theta roles, then. Of course the subordinate clause (not "phrase" -- there's a predicate with arguments here) has its own cycle, with _Jane_ as subject, and _book_ as object, and the whole clause marked by the `Acc`-_ing_ gerund complementizer. Context will determine whether _Jane_ is raised in addition.

Comment: @jlawler Jane cannot be subject here, because the name could easily be replaced with "her" without changing any of the sentence's grammar. You could NOT say, "Tom saw she reading the book." You would say, "Tom saw _her_ reading the book." "Her" is never a subject. Thus it is not a subordinate clause, as a clause requires a subject.

Comment: _She_ is the pronoun used as subject of tensed clauses. But _her_ is the pronoun used as subject of gerund clauses. You're right that they can't be substituted for one another.

Comment: In "Tom saw [Jane reading the book]", Jane is only the _understood_ subject of the bracketed catenative complement clause. Syntactically, "Jane" is object of the matrix clause, i.e. object of "saw".

Comment: @BillJ Now I disagree. The gerund phrase/clause is a constituent. It passes the tests for constituents, e.g. clefting, _It was Jane reading the book that Tom saw_; pseudoclefting, e.g. _What Tom saw was Jane reading the book_; Answer fragments, e.g. _What did Tom see? -- Jane reading the book_, passivization, e.g. _Jane reading the book was seen by Tom_, proform subsitution, e.g. _Tom saw that_ (_that = Jane reading the book_). I would agree with you if the test sentence were _Tom saw Jane read the book_. In such a case, the string _Jane read the book_ no longer behaves as a constituent.

Comment: @TimOsborne Instead of “It was Jane reading the book that Tom saw” I would have “It was Jane that Tom saw reading the book”, and for the passive, instead of “Jane reading the book was seen by Tom”, I would say “Jane was seen reading the book by Tom” (or “Jane was seen by Tom reading the book”). Note also “The children were seen playing in the garden by their grandmother”, not *”The children playing in the garden was seen by their grandmother”.

Comment: @BillJ, I agree that the alternatives you present are good, but I also think that the versions I presented are possible. Further evidence comes from the ability to appear with the copula in subject position, e.g. _Tom laughing was an annoyance to all of us_. Note as well that regardless of which structural analysis one assumes, the name _Tom_ is a constituent.

Comment: @BillJ, The comparison with an example such as _Tom saw Jane leave_ is also relevant. In this case, there is little evidence that _Jane leave_ is a constituent. Clefting _??It was Jane leave that Tom saw_, pseudoclefting _??What Tom saw was Jane leave_, answer fragment _What did you see? --*Jane leave_, subject of copula _*Jane leave was an annoyance to all of us_, passivization *Jane leave was seen by Tom_. This same reasoning identifies the nominal+to-infinitve in control and raising structures as a non-constituent in sentences such as _Tom believes Jane to have red the book_.

Comment: I think my "children" examples prove conclusively that "reading the book" is not part of the object but catenative complement of "saw". Likewise, *"Jane reading the book was seen by Tom" is ungrammatical, proving that the Od is just "Jane". If what you say is correct, the whole catenative concept would be invalid, which would be a ridiculous claim.

Answer (score 1):

The complement of *saw*, *Jane reading the book*, is, categorially speaking, an **IP** whose I(nfl) head is the non-finite affix *-ing*, with a subject *Jane* in Spec I position (but **not a CP**, i.e., not a complete 'clause', against what jlawler's comment claims). That IP is, indeed, theta-marked by *saw* with the role traditionally called 'Theme'. It is not, however, Case-marked by *saw*, because IPs cannot absorb Case, which entails that the accusative Case feature that *saw* can assign remains available to be absorbed by some available DP (i.e., *Jane*, in this case).

As non-finite I(nfl) *-ing* cannot assign Case (except 'null' Case to PRO in constructions like *I enjoyed [ __[PRO reading the book]]*, where *enjoyed* takes a full CP complement), in *I saw Jane reading the book*, *Jane* then 'exceptionally' receives accusative Case from *saw* (one of the 'exceptional Case marking' (ECM) verbs - which, at bottom, means a small number of verbs that **may** select IP instead of CP complements). The difference is that the DP occupying the Spec I of IP complements is not 'protected' by the CP barrier and remains accessible to Case-marking by an external verb, *saw* in this case, whereas the PRO subject of full CPs is inside the CP barrier and inaccessible to the higher verb (*enjoyed*, in my example above).

Evidence for the classical analysis just offered comes from at least two simple facts: one is that * *I saw [**PRO** reading the book]* is ungrammatical (whereas e.g. *I enjoyed [__ [PRO reading the book]]* is not), and it is ungrammatical because its PRO subject is **doubly Case-marked** (as 'null' Case by the IP-internal *-ing* Infl, and as accusative by the governing verb *saw*; the other is that when the higher verb *see* appears in passive form and so loses its transitivity and its capacity to assign accusative Case, as in *__ was **seen** [__ reading the book]*, the lower subject *Jane* can no longer receive accusative Case from *see* and, to avoid violating the Case Filter, must raise from Spec IP into the Spec T of the main clause and become its subject, as in ***Jane*** was seen [ **t** reading the book]. This, in turn, entails that the *ing*-clause cannot have a PRO subject after ECM verbs like *see*, since it has a trace-of-*Jane* one, and so that it must be an IP, not a CP, Q.E.D.

Comment: this is good, i'm glad you answered this. one minor clarification question i have is the distinction between these ECM cases and the usual infinitival ones, eg with _persuade_. it seems there are some differences, for instance an adverbial can intervene between the ECM subject with _persuade_ (I persuaded John quite easily to give the lecture). is this  possible with -ing examples, eg maybe: I saw Bill clearly reading the book (where _clearly_ is supposed to modify _saw_, not _reading_).

Comment: @BillJ The evidence from tests for constituents reveals that the string _John to give the lecture_ in the sentence _I persuaded John to give the lecture_ is NOT a constituent, whereas the string _Bill reading the book_ in the sentence _I saw Bill reading the book_ IS a constituent. See my message above in this regard. In a phrase structure grammar that assumes strict binary of branching, the difference is a problem, because the relevant strings are likely analyzed as constituents in both cases.

Comment: @tim modern approaches to syntax are more sophisticated than just "does this string pass certain constituency tests?" most of the traditional tests (substitution, coordination, etc) are super unreliable. further, not all constituents are even predicted to pass constituency tests. single-bar-level projections for example can't be targeted for movement

Comment: @one-off-post Tests for constituents are on the whole a big problem for phrase structure syntax, so your comment is not surprising for me, since you seem like a true proponent of Chomskyan phrase structure. The tests are, though, more consistent with dependency syntax. I have worked on the issue in detail. If you can be open-minded about the matter, have a read here: https://journals.helsinki.fi/lud/issue/view/15